# Empty MySQL database table cell triggers "Content" switch

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a really weird problem with my MySQL database. To make sure I wasn't make a dumb mistake, I tested it without the database...

```
$Content = 'Hello World';
// $Content = '';
switch ($Content)
{
 case '':
 echo 'No Content 1';
 break;
 default:
 echo 'Content 1';
 echo $Content;
 echo '<br><br>';
 break;
}
```

It works. When content equals 'Hello World' it echoes "Content 1." When I set it to $Content = '', it echoes "No Content 1."

But when I delete the first two lines and insert "Hello World" in my database, something funny happens.

Actually, it works correctly at first. But when I delete the content from the database, it still displays "Content 1," even though there's no database content. (It doesn't echo the value for $Content.)

I checked the database to see if there might be a 0 (zero) in the cell, but there isn't. There isn't even a simple space.

On a whim, I added the value 0 to my switch:

```
switch ($Content)
{
 case '':
 case 0:
 echo 'No Content I';
 break;
 default:
 echo 'Content I<br><br>';
 echo $Content;
 break;
}
```

Now it does just the opposite, display "No Content" whether there's content in the database or not.

Am I making some simple mistake? I upgraded MAMP a couple days ago, so I wondered if it might be some kind of software bug.

**ON EDIT:** I Googled for more information and found this solution...

```
if ($Content != 0) {
 echo "true";
 echo $Content;
} else {
echo "false";
echo $Content;
}
```

However, it doesn't work for me, either; it returns "false" where there's content in the database or not.

Comment: sometimes database query calls return false, which matches 0 in this case. Show the result of var_dump($Content) before the switch + the way you set $Content from the database

Comment: OK, when there's no database content, var_dump displays this: string(42) "" ... however, the last quote is on the next line. When I put content in the database, it displays this: string(53) "Hello World
" As you can see, the last quote is on the next line, again.

Comment: I don't know if this is significant, but the field Type = longtext, and Default = Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) uses [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), which means that non-empty strings are interpreted as 0 when comparing with an integer, unless the initial portion of the string converts to a non-zero number according to the rules in [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).